# How to check if user logged with facebook Laravel 5

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5

I need to check if user logged and if he logged then to use data trought app(save data to database and get welcome message) here is my code:

```
 <?php namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticator;
    use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
    use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
    use App\UserListener;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Guard;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class AuthenticateUser {
        private $users;
        private $socialite;


        public function __construct(UserRepository $users,  Socialite $socialite) {
            $this ->users = $users;
            $this ->socialite= $socialite;

        }

        public function execute($hasCode){
          if(! $hasCode) return $this -> getAuthorizationFrist();  
         $user = $this -> users -> findOrCreate($this -> getFacebookUser());

              redirect('/login');


        }
        private function getAuthorizationFrist(){
            return $this -> socialite ->driver('facebook')->redirect();
        }

        private function getFacebookUser(){
         return $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();


        }

    }
?>
```

Here is controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\AuthenticateUser;


    class AuthController extends Controller{
    public function login(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser,Request $request){
           return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'));
        }
     }
?>
```

execute function will check if 'code' exist if exists I will get user data into $user variable and then redirect to login, I need some example how can I check if that user logged and write welcome message...I using laravel packetage socialite...`enter code here`

Also here is route, but not working:

```
get('face',function(){
    if(Auth::check()) return 'Wlecome,' .Auth::user()->username;

    return 'Hi guest.' . link_to('login', 'login to face');
});

get('login','AuthController@login');
```

Comment: So what do you see. What does not work?

Comment: Don't work this part: Auth::check() user is logged but I get this message:Hi guest.login to face...So there I should check if user logged and wirte this message: Welcome Name...